# App Store Connect Rejects Binary w/ ITMS-90562 Invalid Bundle - Unable to Compile Bitcode

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, bitcode

On builds submitted with Xcode 11b2, after successfully uploading a build I'm getting an email a few minutes later with the following message:

> ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - The app submission can not be successfully recompiled from bitcode due to missing symbols during linking. You can try to reproduce and diagnose such issues locally by following the instructions from: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2432/_index.html

Following the link, I'm able to export an ad-hoc build with bitcode without any errors locally so it doesn't seem to be much help.

I've also tried submitting builds with the checkbox for bitcode both on and off, though the app in question includes an Apple Watch app and that platform always requires bitcode so it may make no real difference.

Anyone seen this before and know how to resolve ?

Comment: Did you set 'Enable Bitcode' to 'YES'? The field is in your targets Build Settings section.

Comment: Yes, the targets are properly set to enable Bitcode and exporting an Ad-Hoc build generates Bitcode successfully.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any idea how to solving it now?

Comment: @OwenZhao Still nothing. I've tried quite a few variations without luck. At this point I'm probably just going to wait for 11b3 and see if that's any better.

Comment: I uploaded another version of my app. The issue seemed gone. However, my app was automatically rejected as Apple's server identified I used non-public APIs. What it pointed as non-public APIs were Combine framework.

Comment: @OwenZhao Same here, 'Invalid Binary' on account of using Combine. Grrr.

Comment: I reported it to Apple for them to fix but once that's resolved hopefully I can close this all out.

Comment: I just got this error with the Xcode 11.0 release.

Comment: I got this error with xcode 11.5

Answer (score 1):

Apple resolved this issue with Xcode 11b3.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with unchecking bitcode tick when uploading the TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be back today. Xcode 11.5, Xcode 11.7, both causing the same error email from AppStoreConnect with the error. We didn't change a thing, of course.

In order to be able to get QA builds to our people, we had to temporarily just no choose "include Bitcode" when submitting it.

Contacted Apple, but the associate answering the phone is only admin type level, not code level, couldn't answer why.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. “Me too” is an anecdote, not an answer.

Comment: first, I wanted to comment but didn't have enough rep. second, this has a workaround that should help people. But I get your point.

Comment: Sure. Points taken (pun intended). But still keeping it here as I am sure it will help people, either by the actual issue, or reading your points on the rules :)

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting to Adhoc to see the logs

Is explained here:

Troubleshooting App Thinning and Bitcode Build Failures
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2432/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use fastlane
just pass `include_bitcode` set to `false` inside `build_app`.
So your `Fastlane` file will look like this:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    get_certificates
    get_provisioning_profile
    build_app(workspace: "AppName.xcworkspace", scheme: "AppName", include_bitcode: false)
    upload_to_testflight
  end
end
```